# Create an anonomous object where the string is the property name

Tags: c#

I want to make an object using the following code:

```
// eg "foo", "bar"
public void MakeObject(string field, string val){
  var update = new {
    field = val
  }

  ... do more things...
}
```

and the resulting object I want will be:

```
{
 foo = "bar"
}
```

But I keep getting:

```
{
 field = "bar"
}
```

Comment: perhaps you need a dictionary?

Comment: `var update = { [field]: val };`

Answer (score 2):

Anonymous types are just regular types that *you don't type yourself*; when you do:

```
new { field = val }
```

that defines an anoynymous type with a single member called `field`, of type `string` (inferred from `string val`).

You can't make an anonymous type pretend to be a type with different member names.

Alternatives:

- use a dictionary

  ```
  new Dictionary<string, string> { { field, val } }
  ```
- if this is for UI / data-binding purposes, there are some "fun" things you can do with the `TypeDescriptor` API to make it *pretend* to have different names (for display purposes). This is an advanced topic, but I can cover it if it is relevant
- probably options involving `dynamic`

How well any of these options work for your scenario really depends on what is *consuming* your object. An object serializer (JSON, XML, etc) might work very differently to a UI data-bound control, which might work very differently to an ORM. So: what is *consuming* this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that you are looking not for *anonymous* object but for [ExpandoObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=netframework-4.8) (which is in fact an implementation of `IDictionary<string, object>`), e.g.

```
  using System.Dynamic;

  ...

  dynamic myObject = new ExpandoObject();

  // Compile-time property
  myObject.foo = "abc";

  // Run-time property
  string propertyName = "bar";

  (myObject as IDictionary<string, object>).Add(propertyName, 123);

  Console.Write($"foo = {myObject.foo}; bar = {myObject.bar}");
```

**Outcome:**

```
  foo = abc; bar = 123
```